# Apple MFi when is that required?

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I used to know that you need `MFi` to any `bluetooth` connection .
Now, i have read in many places that with low power bluetooth on the `iPhone4S` , you dont need that.
I am confused: if i put a bluetooth low power chip , can i make an app that connect to it ?
or do we still need the `MFi` ?

http://blog.bluetooth-smart.com/2011/11/03/iphone-4s-says-goodbye-to-mfi-for-bluetooth-smart-devices/

does these guys are using it ?

https://www.sticknfind.com/?utm_source=adroll_display&utm_medium=retargeting&utm_campaign=display

Answer (score 0):

MFi is needed only for classic Bluetooth development. For BLE, CoreBluetooth framework is used and you don't need MFi for that.